# Launch Page in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, rubygems, launch

Is there anything like [LaunchRock](http://launchrock.com/), but in the form of a Gem? It'd be something that says "X is the Y of Z", have a slick-looking background, and an email address one can use to get an early invite

I mean something that automates a launch page, even if a launch page is extremely simple in of itself, I wanted to see if a gem existed already that does it.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, gems don't create applications for you - they only give you certain specific functionalities, such as pagination of many records.

If you want it to say 'X is the Y of Z', then type that in a `div` in your page. If you want to build an application with a 'slick looking background', put a `background-image` in your html. And, if you want to save an e-mail address to a database, build your controller actions and migrations and get it working.

Answer (score 0):

something like this may help: http://vinsol.com/blog/2011/06/21/launching-soon-%E2%80%93-helping-startups-build-online-identity-even-before-the-actual-launch/